# Angular2 router: different modules on same Home component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i've read the entire routing documentation on angular2, and also searched for an answer, but I didn't found a solution for this.

[image: image showing what i want to achieve]

I have an app with different feature modules. The routes of each feature module should be defined inside each feature module. I want to have a Home Component, with a menu that let me navigate to each feature, a top bar, footer, etc, and also a `router-outlet` in the center of the page. 
**I want to have each feature module rendering in that `router-outlet`.**

How should I handle this scenario?

In another posts its also called **Hierachy of modules** (although I have no extensive hierachy, simply one Module called home, containing all other feature modules)

I created this and is not working (the feature module is displayed in the entire page instead of inside the home's `router-outlet`):

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    **HomeModule**,
    **routing**,
],
declarations: [
    ...
],
providers: [
    ...
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.routing.ts** these are default routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**home.module.ts** This is the main home module. The module imports here al feature modules (FamiliaModule is an example)

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    FamiliaModule
],
declarations: [

],
providers: [

]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

**familia.module.ts** Finally, one feature module defining its routes.

```
const familiaRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'familias', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: FamiliasComponent}

];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(familiaRoutes),
    PanelModule,
    ButtonModule,
    PanelMenuModule,
    DataTableModule,
    SharedModule,
    DropdownModule,
    DialogModule,
    InputTextModule
],
declarations: [
    FamiliasComponent
],
providers: [
    AlertService,
    FamiliaService,
    EstadoService
]
})
export class FamiliaModule {}
```

How do I make FamiliaModule show inside HomeComponent? Has RootModule.forRoot or forChild something to do with it? Now, when I go to `/` I can see the home view, but when I navigate to `/familias`, the FamiliaComponent replaces the home view with the menus, headers, etc and is displayed in the entire page.

Thanks!!

## Edit

Added image for clarification

## Edit #2

Here is the home.component.html

```
<div id="layout-sidebar">
    <img class="logo-sidebar" />
    <p-panelMenu [model]="menuItems" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>
</div>
<div id="layout-content">
    <div id="top-bar">
        <span class="ui-widget">Bienvenido, <b>{{currentUser.nombre}}</b>!</span>
        <button icon="fa-sign-out" pButton [routerLink]="['/login']" label="Cerrar sesión"></button>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this.

```
 {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],  
 {path:'familia', component: FamiliaComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    ...
```

And in your home component html you can use something like this

```
 <!---  title bar ---!>
 <!---  side bar ---!>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also, you can try to use lazy loading your modules to make your app faster. Just google it cause other sources can explain it better than me.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see how an outlet can resolve the problem. The problem is that FamiliaComponent renders on the `router-outlet` of the app.main.ts and not on the home.module.ts. Where should I insert my HomeComponent ?

Comment: Can you show your home.routing.ts and familia.routing.ts? Because in your home component you can insert another <router-outlet>

Comment: Thanks Brian, I added an image for clarification. I can add the outlet in the homecomponent, but the HomeComponent is never used! I dont know where to put it

Comment: @jigarzon I edited my answer. Let me know if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks @brian-g but that is not solving the issue: when the route is "/" it is handled Ok by HomeComponent... when it is "/familia", it is handled by FamiliaComponent BUT it occupies the entire screen, its not inside the homecomponent...

Comment: May i know where did you put your router-outlet? If it's in your app.component.html it would occupy the whole screen.

Comment: Just to add. The router-outlet should be inside your home.component.html. If you could share your templates I can help you more.

Comment: I added that code! As i've said, the feature component (like FamiliaComponents) are rendering using the app.component's router-outlet (that is the outlet used for login, where home component is inserted)

Comment: I see. One more thing. I'm assuming a lot of things here. In your index.html did you put your <home> directive there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139260/discussion-between-brian-g-and-jigarzon).